# Custom Campaigns with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I used to work with Google Analytics and build Custom Campaigns with the Campaign URL Builder.
Once I've moved to Google Tag Manager, I've stopped seeing any new campaigns in my Google Analytics page.

some facts:

- No I'm not an idiot, and I've triple checked that I'm building the URL right in the Campaign Builder. (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/)
- Again, I'm not an idiot, there are no Filters In my GA which hides all the new Campaigns.
- I'm getting this error in my GA page:
  "Property betzavta.me is not receiving hits. Either your site is not receiving any sessions or it is not tagged correctly."
  => though all the other GA functionalities are working currectly (Events, logged users, Real Time data and so on...)
- I did install the Tag assistant chrome extension, and it only gave me warnings which say that I should ignore those warnings :-) :-)

Is there anything specific (Trigger, Tag, Variable) that I should define in GTM so the campaign URL will be sent to GA, because so far I didn't see anything about that.
Again, all the other GA things have migrated successfuly to the GMT ( the GMT sends them correctly to the GA).

[All my Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VpHe.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GTM is nothing more than an additional layer between site and GA. GTM doesn't do anything by itself, so utm parameters don't reach GA (and we presume they are correct), then you did something wrong setting up GA through GTM. What exactly you did wrong - it is pure guesswork, unless you provide more details. At least, example of a utm-tagged link and screenshot of the settings of you main GA tag in GTM.

Comment: All my other GA functionalities works well through the GTM. As i said i didn't find any special tag or trigger of the campaign, is it something that should do?
If so, then how?